# task scheduler after 5 min

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db=mysql_select_db("test");
    $i=1;
    $r=" INSERT INTO test1 (score) VALUES ('$i') "  ;
    $t=mysql_query($r);
    if($t)
    {
    $d="select score from test1";
    $x=mysql_query($d);
$count=mysql_num_rows($x);
if($count>0)
{ 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($x))
{

   $i=$row['score']+5;

    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    }}}
```

In this I am just inserting the $i value into the database ie 1 , after that by using select i capture the last value and add 5 in it but it is not working and i cant use the session also because i am working on task scheduler , it means after 5 mins my script will run and update the database but in my database it just showing 1 only

Comment: But you just add five, where you update your data?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: You don't update the Database after the increment. In the loop you should add: `mysql_query("UPDATE test1 SET score=score+5");` - (BTW , follow @JasonMcCreary suggestion)

Comment: you get your variable add 5 and get out, but you need to do an update inside your database to add the 5 in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db=mysql_select_db("test");
$i=1;


$d="select score from test1 order by id desc limit 1 ";
$x=mysql_query($d);
$count=mysql_num_rows($x);
if($count>0) { 
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($x))
   $i=$row['score']+5;
}

$r=" INSERT INTO test1 (score) VALUES ('$i') "  ;
$t=mysql_query($r);
?>
```

Comment: @Jitender Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource in **$count=mysql_num_rows($x)**                                            i guess ur $row=mysql_fetch_rows($x) should b like this while($row=mysql_fetch_array($x))

Answer (score 1):

The Insert Should be Performed after select, then you will be able to insert the updated value.

Currently you are getting the value from database add `5` to it and then leave. and insert has already been done for `1` in the start of the script

Comment: Yes, that is correct, if you update the variable, its not directly linked to the database, not linked at all. So you need to update the data or insert AFTER the increment is done.. just to complement ^^